# Method 'createpivottable' of object 'pivotcache' failed after Windows re-image

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel workbook which uses VBA to create multiple pivot tables on multiple sheets based off the same PivotCache. My organisation has been using this workbook for sometime.

Recently I had to have my workstation re-imaged with Windows and now this workbook fails to execute. One pivot table will be created but if a second is created with the same cache the method fails to execute.

I can only think this has something to do with the versioning of Excel since it worked before the re-image. The code is below:

```
  ' SET Cache for ALL PIVOT TABLES
Set PVC = qqOutBook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, "rawdata!" & Range(r.Cells(1, 1), r.Cells(erow, ecol)).Address, 6)

' PIVOT 1
Call Pivot1AND2(p1, PVC, "041")

' PIVOT 2
Call Pivot1AND2(p2, PVC, "042")

' PIVOT 2
Call Pivot3(p3, PVC)
```

Function below fails on the second call

```
Sub Pivot1AND2(ByVal p As Worksheet, ByVal PVC As PivotCache, ByVal Whs As String)

p.Activate

'FIRST pivot
Set pt = PVC.CreatePivotTable(p.Name & "!R7C1", p.Name, 6)
```

Can not pass this point on the second try.

Has anyone else experienced a versioning issue with this method?

Comment: How exactly does it fail - do you get an error message, and if so, what is it?

Comment: It fails and gives the error message in the title of the question.

Comment: Sorry - missed the title...

Comment: Not sure why, but give it a try (I had something similar and it worked), after you `Set pt` once, clear the `PivotCache`, then re-Set it, and then call your `Sub Pivot1AND2` for the second (and third) time

Comment: @ShaiRado so that is the solution I ended up going with but I still don't understand why this happened in the first place. Seems like an environment impact on excel to me but I don't have the background to dive in deeper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was originally in the comments above.

The workaround is to clear the Pivot Cache and set the Pivot Table again.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem as @Matt. I have a macro in a workbook which creates another workbook with 4 pivot tables. It's been working for over a year. A few days ago, it failed on the second pivot table with the message in this thread's title.

Clearing the pivot cache variable (by setting it to Nothing) and resetting it fixed the problem. I did this before pivot tables 2 thru 4. But the workbook is now 67% larger.

I have Office 365 on Windows 10. I'm assuming Microsoft applied an update which caused this problem.

Comment: I think an update is what caused this issue as well. This issue has only affected some users but not all. All of which have windows 10 office 365

Comment: This may be the same problem: [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-msoffice_custom-mso_2016/run-time-error-2147417848-80010108-method/4cc2bdf3-09c4-4ffc-a20a-add11ced3354)

Answer (score 1):

Workaround may no longer be necessary. My original workbook which stopped working a month ago now works again! I can only assume a Microsoft update fixed the problem.